# The get and set property appears to be ignored (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to modify the "set" portion, but these changes don't seem to take place at all. Here is the basic code that shows the same results:

```
class Class1
{
    private int num;

    public Class1(int number)
    {
        num = number;
    }
    public int getNumber
    {
        get 
        { 
            return num;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                num = value;
            else
                num = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

In here, I want to make any negative value a 0.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1(10);
        Class1 c2 = new Class1(-10);

        Console.WriteLine(c1.getNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(c2.getNumber);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The result gives me

`10
-10`

I've tried using

```
        set
        {
            num = 100;
        }
```

yet there's still no change in the results. I've tried double checking with the book I'm using, and there's no difference that I can see. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 if it means anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not calling set portion of your property. Because, you are only calling constructor.  And in your constructor you are only setting tha value for the backing field variable(`num`).
Also, [by convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229004.aspx), your class members names are not appropriate.
Change it as:

> num -> number 
> getNumber -> Number

Try this:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.Number = -10; // The set accessor is invoked here
int myNumber = c1.Number; // The get accessor is invoked here
```

If you want to invoke set accessor through your constructor, then change your constructor as:

```
public Class1(int number)
{
      Number = number;
}
```

Then it will invoke set accessor properly:

```
 Class1 c1 = new Class1(10); // The set accessor will be invoked
```

And don't forget to change your class implementation as:

```
class Class1
{
    private int number;

    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                number = value;
            else
                number = 0;
        }
    }

    // If you do provide a constructor (any constructor with any signature), 
    // the parametrless constructor will not be generated
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public Class1(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

Read [this from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx) for additional information.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thank you! Can you tell me why the class implementation should be organized that way?

Comment: @Alex Because, it is convention. Coding conventions are a set of guidelines for a specific programming language. Software programmers are highly recommended to follow these guidelines to help improve the readability of their source code and make software maintenance easier. I recommend to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Class1
{
    private int num;

    public Class1(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
    public int Number
    {
        get 
        { 
            return num;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                num = value;
            else
                num = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

You hadn't implented it correctly. Actually a better implmentation would be the following:

```
class Class1
{
    // The backing field has the same name as the Property
    // but all letters must be lowercase.
    private int number;

    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                number = value;
            else
                number = 0;
        } 
    }

    // In the constructor we set the value of the backing fields
    // using the corresponding properties.
    public Class1(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

The each time you want to set the value of `number` or get it's value you use the corresponding property:

```
// Set the value 2 to the number
Number = 2;

// Read the value stored in number and assigned to value.
var value = Number;
```